# python: how to get all members of an array except for ones that match a condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an array of all .asm files I need to build *except* for one that is causing me trouble right now. Here's what I have, based on the Scons ["Handling Common Cases"](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/a10760.html) page:

```
projfiles['buildasm'] = 
  ['#build/'+os.path.splitext(x)[0]+'.asm' for x in projfiles['a']];
```

(this maps paths of the form 'foo.a' to '#build/foo.asm')

I want to run this for each member of `projfiles['a']` *except* if a member of the array matches 'baz.a'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
projfiles['buildasm'] = ['#build/'+os.path.splitext(x)[0]+'.asm' for x in projfiles['a'] if x != 'baz.a']
```

or more generally:

```
ignored_files = ['baz.a',
                 'foo.a',
                 'xyzzy.a',
                 ]
projfiles['buildasm'] = ['#build/'+os.path.splitext(x)[0]+'.asm' for x in projfiles['a'] if x not in ignored_files]
```

Comment: thanks... most of Python's syntax is new to me. If ignored_files is a large list, is it better to use a dictionary lookup rather than an array?

Comment: Its best to use a set() then.